# How do I remove StackEgg from Stack Exchange pages?

Tags: support, stackegg

How do I remove the StackEgg game from top right hand side of the SE pages?

Comment: You could have waited **61 minutes and 25 seconds**. StackEgg will be gone in another 32 minutes from the time of this comment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Click the StackEgg animation in the sidebar to open the popup.
2. Click the **?** (help and settings) button on the top-right of the popup.

   [image]
3. Enable the "remove the StackEgg from the site's sidebar" option in the settings.

   [image]

Or, it'll be gone very shortly anyway!

---

If you want to re-enable StackEgg, click the link in the footer:

[image]

Comment: And I saw there is a 're-enable StackEgg' link almost at the bottom of the page

Comment: few hours -> < 1 hour.